# How to specify allocate dependency for a struct property

Tags: redhawksdr

I am attempting to write a component to interface with the USRP_UHD device using the DigitalTuner port.  The USRP_UHD is looking for a property with the id == "FRONTEND::tuner_allocation" in the allocateCapacity function.  This is the id of a struct property.  How do I specify this as a dependency in my component that I am attempting to interface with the USRP_UHD device?  I was able to successfully create a allocation dependency on a simple property with the action set to external, but could not figure out how to do this for a struct property.

Is there an example of a component that controls the USRP_UHD somewhere?

Update:  I believe I figured it out.  I was trying to do a allocate dependency when it should be a usesdevice  dependency.  Could someone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct.  To interface with the USRP_UHD using the DigitalTuner port you'll need a component or service which contains an output Front end Interfaces DigitalTuner port.

To automatically connect the USRP's input digital tuner port to your service or components output digital tuner port you'll have to create a usesdevice dependency similar to the XML displayed in this previous stack overflow answer: [REDHAWK UHD device usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570767/redhawk-uhd-device-usage/16612555#16612555)

If there were any gotcha's or tricky parts to this please expand on your question or self-answer so others may benefit from your experiences.