# Allocating tuner on Frontend 2.0 compliant device in Java

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm developing a Frontend 2.0 interface compliant device using Redhawk 1.9 on RHEL 5.  My implementation is using Java, and I have a test framework set up within JUnit to ease testing and metrics during development.  I'm hoping to make an automated test that allocates a single available tuner by passing in a "FRONTEND::tuner_allocation" struct property.  Using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885483/allocation-of-front-end-ii-interface-compliant-device), I came up with the following code:

```
List<DataType> props = new LinkedList<DataType>();
props.add(new DataType("FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::tuner_type", AnyUtils.toAny("DDC", TCKind.tk_string)));
props.add(new DataType("FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::allocation_id", AnyUtils.toAny(allocId, TCKind.tk_string)));
props.add(new DataType("FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::center_frequency", AnyUtils.toAny(98700000.0, TCKind.tk_double)));
props.add(new DataType("FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::bandwidth", AnyUtils.toAny(200000.0, TCKind.tk_double)));
props.add(new DataType("FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::bandwidth_tolerance", AnyUtils.toAny(25.0, TCKind.tk_double)));
props.add(new DataType("FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::sample_rate", AnyUtils.toAny(200000.0, TCKind.tk_double)));
props.add(new DataType("FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::sample_rate_tolerance", AnyUtils.toAny(25.0, TCKind.tk_double)));
props.add(new DataType("FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::device_control", AnyUtils.toAny(true, TCKind.tk_boolean)));
props.add(new DataType("FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::group_id", AnyUtils.toAny("", TCKind.tk_string)));
props.add(new DataType("FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::rf_flow_id", AnyUtils.toAny("", TCKind.tk_string)));

DataType[] tunersToAllocate = new DataType[1];
tunersToAllocate[0] = new DataType("FRONTEND::tuner_allocation", AnyUtils.toAny(props, TCKind.tk_struct));

try
{
    assertTrue(rhDevice.allocateCapacity(tunersToAllocate));
}
catch (InvalidCapacity invalidCapacity)
{
    logger.error("Unexpected allocation failure (invalid capacity)", invalidCapacity);
    assertTrue(invalidCapacity.getMessage(), false);
}
catch (InvalidState invalidState)
{
    logger.error("Unexpected allocation failure (invalid state)", invalidState);
    assertTrue(invalidState.getMessage(), false);
}
```

However, this results in a null pointer exception within the final AnyUtils.toAny() call, since the version of toAny() that takes TCKind apparently does not support non-primitive types:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.ossie.properties.AnyUtils.insertInto(AnyUtils.java:636)
at org.ossie.properties.AnyUtils.toAny(AnyUtils.java:606)
at org.ossie.properties.AnyUtils.toAny(AnyUtils.java:616)
at com.<company-name>.redhawk.nsi.test.NsiClientDeviceTest.testAllocateTuner(NsiClientDeviceTest.java:247)
```

Line 247 is the line with "toAny(props, TCKind.tk_struct)".

Looking at the AnyUtils class code, it seems I should be passing a TypeCode instead.  However, I'm unsure how to get a TypeCode for a struct property, since the code for getComplexTypeCode() and getPrimitiveTypeCode() look like they both do not contain checks for struct types.

Am I going about this the wrong way entirely?  If not, how do I indicate that I want to create an Any of type struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struct properties are packed into CORBA Anys as CF.Properties, but unfortunately, there is no method in AnyUtils to do that. Instead, you have to create the Any and then insert your value into it. User-defined CORBA data types like CF.Properties have a generated helper class with insert and extract methods that work with Anys, while primitive types can be inserted or extracted via the Any's member functions.

The following code snippet creates an Any via the ORB and uses the static CF.PropertiesHelper.insert() method to store the properties in it:

```
org.omg.CORBA.Any tunerAlloc = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init().create_any();
CF.PropertiesHelper.insert(tunerAlloc, props.toArray(new DataType[props.size()]));
tunersToAllocate[0] = new DataType("FRONTEND::tuner_allocation", tunerAlloc);
```

The generated CORBA helpers only work with arrays, so Java Collections types have to be converted (in the above example, it's done in-line). If you have your own ORB reference, you can use that instead of ORB.init().

Comment: Worked for me; didn't think of just making the Any manually via insert() since I'm fairly new to the concept.  Thanks!